# How to update the android sdk manager manually?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I have already updated all the API and packages. Recently i reinstalled my computer so when i opened eclipse all my packages are gone.I copied all the contents of sdk to my new sdk folder but still it shows that have to install many packages and API.

Comment: press the sdk manager button at the menu and update all the api's.

Comment: Click on the Android SDK Manager button, it will open. Select all you want to import. Wait for some **geological eras** to complete, then do `Help/Check for updates`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i heard that when you update through sdk manager there is a bug.Our Eclipse will not work,it will say to update to the latest version.Inorder to avoid that we have copy some files manually.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse or Android Studio, click SDK Manager in the toolbar or From Eclipse (with ADT), select Window > Android SDK Manager.

You can select which packages you want to download by toggling the checkboxes on the left, then click Install to install the selected packages.

List of packages required:

1. SDK Tools
2. SDK Platform-tools
3. SDK Platform
4. System Image
5. Android Support
6. SDK Samples